Error in if (b[i, "DataSet"] == "B") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
I want to edit two columns of my seurat object's meta.data by using the following script. I always have used this and it had worked. but now it returns the following error.
Could anyone help me fix it?
b <- NKT_H@meta.data

for (i in 1:nrow(b) ){
  if (b[i, 'DataSet'] == "A"){
    b[i , 'DataSet'] <- "H" 
    b[i , 'orig.ident'] <- "H"
  }
  if (b[i, 'DataSet'] == "B"){
    b[i , 'DataSet'] <- "I" 
    b[i , 'orig.ident'] <- "I"
  }
  if (b[i, 'DataSet'] == "C"){
    b[i , 'DataSet'] <- "J"
    b[i , 'orig.ident'] <- "J"
  }
  if (b[i, 'DataSet'] == "D"){
    b[i , 'DataSet'] <- "K"
    b[i , 'orig.ident'] <- "K"
  }
}


Error:
Error in if (b[i, "DataSet"] == "B") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "H") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "H") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated


I also tried this way:
b <- NKT_H@meta.data
b$DataSet <- factor(b$DataSet, levels=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
b$orig.ident <- factor(b$orig.ident, levels=c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))

for (i in 1:nrow(b) ){
  if (b[i, 'DataSet'] == "A"){
    b[i , 'DataSet'] <- "H" 
    b[i , 'orig.ident'] <- "H"
  }
  if (b[i, 'DataSet'] == "B"){
    b[i , 'DataSet'] <- "I" 
    b[i , 'orig.ident'] <- "I"
  }
  if (b[i, 'DataSet'] == "C"){
    b[i , 'DataSet'] <- "J"
    b[i , 'orig.ident'] <- "J"
  }
  if (b[i, 'DataSet'] == "D"){
    b[i , 'DataSet'] <- "K"
    b[i , 'orig.ident'] <- "K"
  }
}

but again that error occurred.

We can reproduce the error like so.
> a <- data.frame(x=as.factor('A'))
> a[a$x == 'A', 'x'] <- 'B'
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "B") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

To understand why this happens, let's look at the levels.
> a <- data.frame(x=as.factor('A'))
> levels(a$x)
[1] "A"

The warning occurs because B is not a level of the factor.
We can recreate the factor and include B as alternative level, then it works.
> a$x <- factor(a$x, levels=c(levels(a$x), 'B'))
> a[a$x == 'A', 'x'] <- 'B'
> a
  x
1 B
> levels(a$x)
[1] "A" "B"

To your example, we can do
> b |> transform(
+   DataSet=factor(DataSet, labels=c('H', 'I', 'J', 'K')), 
+   orig.ident=factor(DataSet, labels=c('H', 'I', 'J', 'K'))
+ )
   DataSet orig.ident
1        H          H
2        H          H
3        H          H
4        H          H
5        I          I
6        K          K
7        I          I
8        I          I
9        H          H
10       K          K
11       J          J
12       K          K
13       J          J
14       K          K
15       H          H
16       H          H
17       I          I
18       K          K
19       I          I
20       I          I

Why it used to work and now it doesn't: Probably the author of the package you're using thought it would be cool to change something into "factor", I'm not sure.

Data:
> dput(b)
structure(list(DataSet = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), orig.ident = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L), levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))

